# Importing single functions in racket & definition window behavior

Tags: racket

The question is this... After I (provide f) in "[file a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7m4j.png)" and (require "file a") in "[file b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEkoF.png)". If I used expressions "[file a's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pyHy.png)" definition window then those expressions are also imported into "[file b's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4Xv7.png)" interaction window.

Is there a way around that, or should I just not use expressions in the definition window unless I intend to use them?

Answer (score 0):

There's not a way around that. Using `require` runs the file that it required, and running your "ch7.rkt" prints the result of that expression.